# Who are the villains at the end of the 90s X-Men cartoon intro?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification, x-men-the-animated-series

At the end of the 90s *X-Men: The Animated Series* intro, there is a clash between Professor Xavier's X-Men and Magneto's team. I recognize most of the villains, but am unable to identify a few of them.

**Who are they, and did they appear in the series at all?**

I have numbered them below according to the screenshot.

1. Magneto
2. Juggernaut
3. ?
4. ?
5. Pyro
6. Mystique
7. Sabertooth
8. ?

[image: X-men villains]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. [Magneto](http://marvel.wikia.com/Erik_Lehnsherr_%28Earth-92131%29) - first appearance: [Enter Magneto](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_3)
2. [Juggernaut](http://marvel.wikia.com/Cain_Marko_%28Earth-92131%29) - first appearance: [The Unstoppable Juggernaut](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_8)
3. [Warpath](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Proudstar_%28Earth-92131%29) - first appearance: [Slave Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_7)
4. [Yuri Topolov](http://marvel.wikia.com/Yuri_Topolov_%28Earth-92131%29)* - first appearance: [Slave Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_7)
5. [Pyro](http://marvel.wikia.com/St._John_Allerdyce_(Earth-92131)) - first appearance: [Slave Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_7)
6. [Mystique](http://marvel.wikia.com/Raven_Darkholme_(Earth-92131)) - first appearance: [Slave Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_7)
7. [Sabretooth](http://marvel.wikia.com/Graydon_Creed,_Sr._(Earth-92131)) - first appearance: [Night of the Sentinels](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_1)
8. [Avalanche](http://marvel.wikia.com/Dominikos_Ioannis_Petrakis_(Earth-92131)) - first appearance: [Slave Island](http://marvel.wikia.com/X-Men:_The_Animated_Series_Season_1_7)

*With the recent 25th anniversary of the show and upcoming accompanying book, [*Previously On X-Men*](http://www.jacobsbrownmediagroup.com/previously-on-x-men.html), some new information has come to light. In the book, Larry Houston, the main designer of the intro said that this character was an animation mistake that was never fixed. From [an article on CBR.com](https://www.cbr.com/x-men-animated-series-mystery-villain/):

> “But the weirdest question asked about the titles concerns the little green man with the big bald head. Who is he? Fan sites have hazarded guesses. I thought I just didn’t know the books well enough. But Larry [Houston – the designer of the credits] recently told me (after a fan asked) that the bald guy was a mistake by AKOM (the animation studio) that they wouldn’t fix. He isn’t anybody! Who he may have been meant to be has long been forgotten. He’s just another example of a flaw caused by lack of time and money, but one that seems to have been forgiven by the fans.

Comment: Magneto's first appearance was a brief cameo in Night of the Sentinels part 1, and first full appearance in Enter Magneto.